# Turning this into a jQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

Can someone please help me turn this code into a `plugin`?

https://codepen.io/spz457/pen/NaNddP

I want to be able to add a class name to an element that comes into the window view. That's what my script does.

```
var isScrolledIntoView = function(element) {
  var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var windowBottom = windowTop + $(window).height();
  var elementTop = $(element).offset().top; 
  var elementBottom = elementTop + $(element).height();

  if ((elementBottom <= windowBottom) && (elementTop >= windowTop)) {
    return true; 
  } 
};

var showButtonAnimation = function(element, className) {
  $(window).on("scroll", function() {
    if (isScrolledIntoView(element)) {
      $(element).addClass(className);
    } else {
      $(element).removeClass(className);
    }
  });
};

showButtonAnimation(".button", "in");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a plugin for your code.  The jquery [How to Create a Basic Plugin](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/) page is very useful for learning how to make plugins.

```
(function($) {

    var isScrolledIntoView = function($element) {
        var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var windowBottom = windowTop + $(window).height();
        var elementTop = $element.offset().top; 
        var elementBottom = elementTop + $element.height();

        return (elementBottom <= windowBottom) && (elementTop >= windowTop);
    };

    $.fn.addClassOnScrollVisible = function(className) {
        var $collection = this;     // the jQuery set the plugin is acting on

        $(window).on("scroll", function() {

            // loop over each element in the collection
            $collection.each(function() {
                var $element = $(this);

                if (isScrolledIntoView($element)) {
                  $element.addClass(className);
                } else {
                  $element.removeClass(className);
                }
            });
        });

        return $collection;     // return the input collection
    };

}(jQuery));

// Usage example:
$(".button").addClassOnScrollVisible("in");
```

Comment: Thank you! This works great and helps me understand how to create a plugin.